# Pause any operations while UIScrollView is scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a big paginated UIScrollView with severals image and views in it. The thing I'm trying to achieve is to pause any background operation while the user is swiping through pages. I need this because the app is downloading and computing stuff and the swipe animations isn't smooth.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you implemented the lazy loading in uiscrollview images.. ? From your question I guess you need to go with lazy loading of images which make your scrollview struck on scrolling..

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSOperationQueue and catch the scroll event in the UIScrollView's delegate to pause/continue the operations.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

     NSBlockOperation *intenseOperation=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        //do intense stuff
     }];

     [queue addOperation:intenseOperation];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
      [queue setSuspended:NO];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
      [queue setSuspended:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think in reverse manner.

Once the image was downloaded in background then update it in UI by using Main thread.

The Main Thread is handling the UI updates.

Based on your description,

"the swipe animations isn't smooth"

You are downloading images on Main thread.

Comment: I'm already downloading and drawing images using Queues. The fact is that I'm doing a lot (really a lot) of stuff in background. I would like to pause ALL OF THEM since I have not control over everything and not everything is in a well known queue.

Comment: what you have tried till now . show some code on background downloads